# Websphere | Spring State Machine | UML Error loading

Tags: websphere, uml, eclipse-emf, spring-statemachine, ecore

I have created a Spring state machine and it works fine in tomcat server, but when i deploy the same into websphere 8.5.5.17, it gives me below error.

I created the process using Papyrus modeler with eclipse.

**Library** -

```
uml-5.0.0-v20140602-0749.jar   
types-2.0.0-v20140602-0749.jar
org.eclipse.emf.common-2.11.0-v20150805-0538.jar
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi-2.11.1-v20150805-0538.jar
org.eclipse.emf.ecore-2.11.1-v20150805-0538.jar
common-2.0.0-v20140602-0749.jar
```

**ERROR LOGS**

```
 Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource$IOWrappedException: Feature 'eGenericType' not found.  
    
Feature 'eGenericType' not found.  uml-5.0.0-v20140602-0749.jar!/org/eclipse/uml2/uml/internal/impl/uml.ecore, 14, 98)

at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.UMLPackageImpl.loadPackage(UMLPackageImpl.java:17522)
        at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.UMLPackageImpl.init(UMLPackageImpl.java:1910)
        at org.eclipse.uml2.uml.UMLPackage.<clinit>(UMLPackage.java:83)

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:146)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:135)
        at org.springframework.statemachine.uml.support.UmlUtils.getResource(UmlUtils.java:77)
        at org.springframework.statemachine.uml.UmlStateMachineModelFactory.build(UmlStateMachineModelFactory.java:77)
        at org.springframework.statemachine.config.model.AbstractStateMachineModelFactory.build(AbstractStateMachineModelFactory.java:82)
        at org.springframework.statemachine.config.AbstractStateMachineFactory.resolveStateMachineModel(AbstractStateMachineFactory.java:518)
        at org.springframework.statemachine.config.AbstractStateMachineFactory.getStateMachine(AbstractStateMachineFactory.java:167)
        at org.springframework.statemachine.config.AbstractStateMachineFactory.getStateMachine(AbstractStateMachineFactory.java:143)
```

**POM Dependencies**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-statemachine-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-statemachine-uml</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

[Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.statemachine/spring-statemachine-uml/2.2.0.RELEASE) are the maven dependencies downloaded with uml dependency.

**Trying to load UML here**

```
       @Bean
        public StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> modelFactory() {
            return new UmlStateMachineModelFactory("path to uml file");
        }
```

**UML Definition**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <uml:Model xmi:version="20131001" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20131001" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML" xmi:id="_lhOv4PgxEeqQrKoLnfoy6A" name="stateMachine">
    
<packageImport xmi:type="uml:PackageImport" xmi:id="_lzF78PgxEeqQrKoLnfoy6A">
    <importedPackage xmi:type="uml:Model" href="pathmap://UML_LIBRARIES/UMLPrimitiveTypes.library.uml#_0"/>
  </packageImport>

<packagedElement/>

    </uml:Model>
```

Comment: It might be an issue with class cache. Try to stop your server and then clear cache using `clearClassCache.bat` and `osgiCfgInit.bat`. If it doesnt help, you can try to disable class sharing using `-Xshareclasses:none` as described here  -  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/urun_rconfproc_jvm.html

Comment: Also check if that path to uml is valid in a way how it is used.

Comment: @Gas Yes path is valid, it loads the uml file. But somehow causes issues with eclipse jar that uml uses internally.

Comment: You could try to check class loading https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/ttrb_classload_viewer.html . And see if the classes are correctly loaded from where you expect.

Comment: @Gas i verified the jars being loaded, "uml-5.0.0-v20140602-0749.jar" si what i have added and is being loaded. But still error appears, i tried updating ecore libs but still no success.